# Make python script to animate vertex points of any object

Tags: python, animation, scripting, keyframes, shape-keys

I am very new to blender and python . i want to make python script which can animate the vertex point of any object (let's example bpy.data.obajects['Cube'])

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
obj.shape_key_add(name="Basis", from_mix=False)

block = obj.shape_key_add(name="1", from_mix=False)  

block.value = 0.0
block.data[0].co = (0,0,0)
block.keyframe_insert(data_path='mute', frame= 0,index=-1)

block.value = 1.0
block.data[0].co = (1,1,1)
block.keyframe_insert(data_path='mute', frame= 50,index=-1)
```

the above code steps works when i set it up by GUI blender , but In script it just set keyframes but no actual animation occur on play

Comment: Well when I press play it does actually "animate", it changes the cube to the object in the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/0G0EGHT

Comment: @WhatAMesh ,  Well the  image you are showing is just final state of that animation and that's what was happening with me too . It instantly  change to next keyframe but what I need is smooth transition between two frames (like an analog not digital , exactly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bpy

cell = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = cell

basis_key = cell.shape_key_add('basis')
basis_key.keyframe_insert('value', frame=0)

deform_key = cell.shape_key_add()
deform_key.data[0].co = ( 5 , 5 , 5)

deform_key.value = 0.0
deform_key.keyframe_insert('value', frame = 0)

deform_key.value = 1.0
deform_key.keyframe_insert('value', frame = 200)
```

the main difference in your script is that you set your data_path as **"mute"** , so just replace **data_path="value"** then it will work fine